# Meteor: Showing loading spinner at initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, preloader

So I just finished my first meteor project. It's a web app for smartphones and tablets which basically crowdsources Q&A sessions at talks/presentations.
It's called [Questful](http://getquestful.com).

Anyways ... my problem is that on initial first load all the JS files meteor needs are not yet in the cache of the client's browser (obviously) ... but especially when smartphones are used to view this web app (which it is targeted at) and the internet connection may is slow as well (--> quite possible when X hundred people use the same WiFi at an event) it takes forever to load the page the first time. (meteor JS Files are approx 500kB in size).

I tested the uploadspeed of my server and I turned out to be around 50 MBit which is ok since it is a quite cheap root.

A standard jQ preloader wont do the job as meteor loads it's JS files in the head so $(function(){}); will fire too late (AFTER all the JS files are loaded which is not what I want).

Do you guys have any idea if it is possible to code a preloader like this one? Or is there one out there?

best regards
Patrick

Answer (score 0):

take a look here https://github.com/oortcloud/unofficial-meteor-faq#how-do-i-know-when-my-subscription-is-ready-and-not-still-loading

basically you need to have your template display a loading indicator by default and then show data once its loaded

assuming you define your helper as `dataLoaded` the template could be something like

```
{{#if dataLoaded}}
  <Show your real data / templates>
{{else}}
  Loading...
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
Problem is: I forgot to mention that the DOM isn't ready yet while all this JS stuff is loaded at initial load (as of said: the JS files are loaded in the head --> no body there yet --> nothing to display).
So a normal loading spinner won't do the job!

I think a proper approach would be the to have a smart package which moves all JS files to the end of the body and include a loading spinner before all these.
But I couldn't find anything like this yet + I don't know if this is currently possible to move meteor's scripts from the head to the end of the body.